# Android Gif ImageView unable to set width to match parent

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I m using GifImageView from [here](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable).

With the below code(without min-height) it just shows a thumbnail size of the gif -

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout1">

            <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/gif"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

the screenshot below shows the third image as the gif.

[image]

I had to set the min-height of the LinearLayout to 300dp so that the gif can fit the whole parent width.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout1"
            android:minHeight="300dp">

            <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/gif"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Now the gif is shown in whole width but the LinearLayout has paddings as the height is 300dp.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

is the answer to autoscaling for all Views.